# How Jquery get textbox array value when checkbox value checked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, textbox

I want to get only textbox value where checked by checkbox, all textbox and checkbox from database array.

```
<tr><?php foreach($arrbook as $book) { ?>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="<?php echo $book['id_book']; ?>"/> <?php echo $book['name_book'];?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="<?php echo $book['book_price']; ?>"/</td>
<?php } ?></tr>
<td><div class="button"><a href="#" onClick="submitbookdata();">Save !</a></div></td></tr>
```

JS

```
<script>
function submitbookdata() {
    var bookidArr = [];
    var bookpriceArr = [];
    $('.book').each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                var current = $(this).val();
                $(this).parents("tr").find(".bookprice").each(function)(index, n) {
                    if ($.each('n').val() == current) {
                        bookpriceArr.push(this.value);
                    }
                });
        }
        bookidArr.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(bookpriceArr);
}
</script>
```

New Question, but almost same with old question, the questions is, in my array PHP code, I try to divide into 3 cells, and when I try to get textbox value, all value textbox in the same row is the same value. so this is the problem code:

```
<?php $cell_index = 1; foreach($arrbook as $book)
 { 
     if ($cell_index == 1)
     {
        <tr>
     }
     <td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="<?php echo $book['id_book']; ?>"/> <?php echo $book['name_book'];?></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="<?php echo $book['book_price']; ?>"/</td>
     <?php echo "\n";?>
     <?php if ( ++$cell_index > 3 )
      { ?>
          </tr>
          <?php echo "\n"; $cell_index = 1; } ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

And the Jquery is the same with last jquery suggestion from you Guru. and now any suggestion for jquery process? thanks.

The html code maybe like this mate:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>COLUMN 1</th>
<th>COLUMN 2</th>
<th>COLUMN 3</th>
<th>COLUMN 4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 1"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="200"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 2"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="200"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 3"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="200"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 4"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="300"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 5"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="200"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 6"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="200"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 7"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="400"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 8"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="400"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="book" class="book" value="Checkbox 9"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bookprice"class="bookprice" value="400"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="button"><a href="#" onClick="submitbookdata();">Save !</a></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show `HTML` instead of `php` script

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for reply, yeah HTML only where I make  the table. and some <div> before table tag.

Comment: @MikeAmq You must edit the question not post it as answer! I've have done that for you and I've flaged your answer to remove! Kindly note this in future!

Comment: @MikeAmq If you post the rendered html from the browser then it will be useful!! Its very difficult to understand the structure you mentioned here!

Comment: oh ya, Guru, ya. ok guru. thank you

Comment: @Guru, so how can I post a new problem? hmm, I don't know to post here, maybe in new thread? or ? any suggestion mate?

Comment: If it is same question then you need to edit it or you will have ask question button to the top right of your screen where you can ask the question! now if you edit the question here and post the rendered html, then I can do something to help you.

Comment: @Guru, I have edit them already guru, please check them. thanks :)

Comment: See in Google chrome there is a developer tools which will be opened if you press `F12`. Please get the rendered html from there! This is `php` code and it makes us difficult to understand it so if it is html then strucutre of you application is easily understandable!!

Comment: oh ok2. yeah, I will try. thank you Guru.

Comment: @Guru, guru I have edit new post, please check them. I hope can make you understand what I mean. ? :)

Comment: Are you there guru? hmm..I try to get value of the textbox in the same row but still get the same value...!

Comment: @Guru, Thank you so much. now the problems is done. thank you Guru. :)

Comment: @MikeAmq Please do accept the answer if it helped you.. :) click the right mark below the arrow marks beside the answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through each `textbox` since you will have only one `textbox` and `checkbox` in each `tr`. When you check `checked` property of each `checkbox` and if it is checked get the `textbox` value associated with it as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/z6oj25je/1/)**

```
function submitbookdata() {
    var bookidArr = [];
    var bookpriceArr = [];
    $('.book').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {// check the checked property with .is
               var current = $(this).val();
               bookpriceArr.push($(this).parents("tr").find(".bookprice").val()) //get the input textbox associated with it
        }
        bookidArr.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(bookpriceArr);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Get the value of `textbox` like this:

`bookpriceArr.push($(this).parents("td").next().find(".bookprice").val())`

It will traverse back to the parent `td` of `checkbox` and then finds next `element` of parent `td` witch is a `td` which contains `textbox` in this case and then finds `textbox` with class `.bookprice` which exists inside it. Now you have to be careful that there should not be any other `element` in between parent `td` of `checkbox` and parent `td` of its corresponding `textbox`

Comment: Hi, Guru, thank you, I will try, and back If successfull guru. thank you so much. :)

Comment: Sure @MikeAmq.. You can check the Demo mentioned in answer if you have any doubt! :)

Comment: Is Working Guru, thank you. yeah I don't need to iterate...you right. thank you Guru. :)

Comment: Anytime. One more thing Do mark it as answer if it has helped you so that others might find this useful someday.. :) Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Guru. are you there? I have one question more...sorry! I will post the code shortly here...